# Replace hashtags in a single pass with regex

Tags: java, regex, hashtag

I want to replace all hashtags in a string with their equivalent tag in Java. Examples:

```
This is a #foo_bar #document about #nothing_but_tags!
```

will result in:

```
This is a foo bar document about nothing but tags!
```

Is this possible in a **one-pass** regex replace? A hashtag may contain many words.

Comment: What are the rules? Remove hash and replace underscore with space? Anything else?

Comment: Yes, no more rule!

Comment: What is the "equivalent tag"?

Comment: It's obvious from the example I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way to do it with a little hack:

```
String str = "#This is a #foo_bar #document about #nothing_but_tags!";
String res = str.replaceAll(" ?#|(?<=#\\w{0,100})_", " ").trim();
```

It would break with hashtags longer than 100 characters, and it would insert a space in place of hash in the tag if it happens to be the first thing in a string (hence a call to `trim()`).

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/nAXFKo)

The 100 character limitation comes from `{0,100}` portion of lookbehind. This is a limitation of Java regex engine: unlike some other regex engines, it requires the lengths of look-aneads and look-behinds to have an explicit upper limit.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you explain a bit about how lookahead works?

Comment: @Mohsen This construct `(?<=#\\w{0,100})_` means "underscore" (at the end) preceded by what's in parentheses after `=`, i.e. `#\\w{0,100}`, which means "a hashtag and up to 100 word characters". None of that gets captured, though: regex engine verifies them as a prerequisite of the match, but only the underscore is really matched. Here is [a link to my favorite tutorial on lookaheads and lookbehinds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).